# How to .htaccess redirect oldpage to newpage with url structure like this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
http://www.mysite.com/play-<File-Name>-<fileid>.html to http://www.mysite.com/<file-name>.html

http://www.mysite.com/play-<File-Name-Here>-page-<pagenumber>.html to http://www.mysite.com/<file-name>/<pagenumber>
```

I want to do the above two redirects with .htaccess. The ones inside <> are dynamic ones. I have tried a lot to redirect old url to new url but it just doesn't seem to work. I hope I am clear on my question.

And thank you in advance for always helping me with .htaccess redirects which I never can learn and get it to work myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect /play-<File-Name>-<fileid>.html http://www.mysite.com/<file-name.html
Redirect /play-<File-Name-Here>-page-<pagenumber>.html http://www.mysite.com/<file-name>.html
```

for more information:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html